# Code signing issue: Is any difference between this two screenshots?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

What is the difference between these two screenshots?

[image]

and

[image]

update: When I uploaded my app on the appstore I got invalid binary. I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry pal, but this sounds like those television "quiz" where they ask you things like: *"Which one is a tool ? A) Hammer B) Banana"* As long as you don't tell us what the problem is you won't get a useful answer.

Comment: DarkDust, I updated the question.

Comment: Ideally you want to only have Debug/Release. Having the "Any iOS SDK" makes 2x the amount of work when you need to change profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the first one you're telling it that the default behavior is to not code sign, but the behavior on "Any iOS SDK" is to go ahead and code sign after all. In the second you're telling it to always code sign. However, since "Any iOS SDK" covers every compilation you're ever going to do on an iOS project, the former is effectively equivalent to the latter in practice.

Comment: Open your Xcode project settings in a text editor and delete the "sign" entries. See this guide: http://paulsolt.com/2012/11/duplicate-code-signing-on-xcode-with-any-ios-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question.

The Debug and Release Targets are not meant for App store submission.  You want to create a Distribution Target, which is usually a clone of your Release Target, except with the Code Signing Identity changed to being your Distribution certificate and Distribution provision file instead of your Developer certificate and provision.  You might also want to make sure to Validate your Distribution build before trying to upload it.

Comment: If you are submitting the app via Xcode, then you get a chance to re-sign the app just before the submission. In that case, a separate Distribution configuration is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For submission to the App Store via iTunes Connect, you need to sign your app with a Distribution Certificate, not a Developer Certificate.

Follow [Apple's step by step guide](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action). It walks you through the whole process even with screenshots.